# Are there languages in which overt morphological accusative case is obligatory on the second conjunct of a conjunction?

Tags: cases

For example: (1) The officer believed [NP Mary and *me*]

Of course, the distribution of ACC pronouns in English doesn't really map onto ACC in overt morphological case languages.

Comment: Every language I can think of with morphological case would use the accusative in a conjunct that's the object of a verb: the verb assigns accusative case to the conjunct, which passes it on to both nouns. Do you mean in cases like "Mary and me went to the store"?

Comment: At the risk of unwarranted generalization, I'd say that *every* language that has an accusative case (not just fossilized forms of it, like English *me*, which can be misleading) requires all conjuncts of a conjunction to be in the accusative case, if the accusative case is warranted at all. Latin example: *Edo [panem](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panem#Latin) et [caseum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caseum#Latin)* (I eat bread and cheese).

Comment: @Draconis, yes - I miswrote the original.  Your example, "Mary and me went to the store", is better.  are [NP1-NOM and NP2-ACC]  constructions permitted in overt case languages?

Comment: @JeremiahCashore Not in any language I speak—but "Mary and me went to the store" is also somewhat stigmatized in English, bordering on ungrammatical.

Comment: Would you mind editing the question to say more clearly what you mean? If so I can write an answer.